# How to set a delay in bat file after SSH'ing into a server?

Tags: batch-file, delay

I have a Cisco switch that seems to have problems randomly. I have been using the same set of commands to fix this switch. The problem is that it is not a permanent fix and it will go down again. I am now trying to set up a bat file that will connect (through putty) into my switch, and run these commands. Currently, I have the following code:

```
@ECHO OFF
putty.exe -ssh "user"@hostname -pw "password" -m "path\command2.txt
```

The issue with this is that my switch is old and slow. It takes a few seconds to become fully functional. I believe the file is trying to run commands before my switch has a chance to accept said commands. I'm looking for a delay command that I could place in-between. I'm struggling with this as it's all one statement and I wasn't able to find another way to break up the statements. If you need any more information please let me know! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you've posted appears only to be one command; so which commands is it trying to run before your switch is fully functional? Please also enter `Timeout /?` at the Command prompt and read it's, usage information output.

Comment: I am using that one command to open a putty session and SSH into my switch and then immediately input the following commands: 

    conf t
    int tu10
    shut
    no shut
I don't believe it's running the command as the SSH session closes after logging in. The reason I am confused on the Timeout command is that my code to SSH AND input commands on the switch is all one statement. I don’t see where I could put the timeout command.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `Timeout` command, that was an answer to your title, how to set a delay in a batch file after the SSHing, but that isn't apparently what you wanted to do. Have you used the full path including drive spec to your text file? What is your current working directory? Is `putty.exe` local to the batch file, or in `%PATH%`? What happens if you turn `Echo`ing `On` and/or add `Pause` to the next line, _(do you get any output)_?

Comment: Sorry I am not the best at explaining haha. I do currently have the full path included to the command file. putty.exe is local. Turning on echo and adding a pause spits out a pause on the cmd screen that shows up. However, it doesn't do anything to the Putty session. I should also explain that when I run this command it opens the CMD prompt (to input the putty command) and the putty session. The putty session is what's closing out after logging in. Sorry if I'm so confusing.

Comment: Do you get any output in the separate putty window? What happens if you change the putty line to, `Start "" /B putty.exe -ssh "user"@hostname -pw "password" -m "C:\pathto\command2.txt"`? _Note also that I've added a closing doublequote to then end, which was missing in your example_.

Comment: I was thinking maybe OP could use `plink` instead of `putty` and wait for responses from the SSH daemon before sending successive commands from command2.txt.  Sort of like TCL's `expect` scripts.  Or OP could store a shell script on the switch if it's Linux / Busybox based, and have plink run that script.  Basically have the command sequence stored on the switch instead of the workstation.  OP also needs to set up a public / private RSA keypair, rather than hard coding his password into the script.